# Aptana Studio - file does not exist

Tags: aptana-studio

I am unable to load my projects into project explore.
[image]

When I try to open this project by navigating  index.html, it show me that file not exist..

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue when adding a file to my project folder from outside of aptana studio. What solved it for me was a refresh on my project explorer window (right click and click refresh - *i think shortcut is f5 maybe*). Then I could see the file in my project explorer then I just double click it from there or re-open it.